If $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$, is $0$ in the domain of $f(x)$?
My calculator states $f(0)=(1+\frac{1}{0})^0$ results in an error. However, Desmos' graphing utility includes $0$ in the domain when the function is plotted.
I understand the problem is a matter of the order of operations. My calculator is performing the divide by zero operation first which results in the error, whereas Desmos is raising $(1+\frac{1}{0})$ to the power of $0$ first resulting in $1$ before the divide by zero error can occur. Which is the correct order of operations? and why?
Applying bodmas/pemdas implies a division by zero error, but I'd expect Desmos to account for this.

Of course it isn't. It is, as written, undefined. You might be able to extend it at $0$ to make it continuous, but it is not,defined at $0$ since $\frac10$ is not defined.

Of course, it isn't defined for negative $x$ near $0,$ so,you only care about continuity on the positive side.

I do find it odd that Desmos returns $f(0) = 1$ for this function, because no, it should be undefined there.

Desmos is still assuming $y^0=1$ is true when $y$ is not a number. That is an error.

But $$\lim_{x\to0+} f(x)=1,$$ so you can make a continuity argument for extending that value to $x=0.$ But as written, it is, by definition, undefined.

Desmos actually gives an "undefined" output if you specifically type in the case of $y=(1+\cfrac{1}{0})^0$. I think that desmos only labels endpoints (the infimum/supremums), stationary points and etc.
